# Y- parameters to z-parameters in Python

Tags: python, matlab

Is there any function in python that converts y parameters to z parameters like matlab's y2z function?
Here is matlab's `y2z()` function [documentation](https://in.mathworks.com/help/rf/ref/y2z.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No built-in Python function for Y-to-Z conversion like MATLAB's `y2z`. However, you can easily implement it.

#### MATLAB Code

```matlab
Y = [1, 2; 3, 4];
Z = y2z(Y);

disp('Y Parameters:');
disp(Y);

disp('Z Parameters:');
disp(Z);
```

#### Python Code

You can use NumPy for matrix operations.

```py
import numpy as np

def y2z(Y):
    Y11, Y12, Y21, Y22 = Y[0, 0], Y[0, 1], Y[1, 0], Y[1, 1]
    D = (1 + Y11) * (1 + Y22) - Y12 * Y21
    Z11 = (1 + Y11 - Y12 * Y21) / D
    Z12 = (Y11 + Y22 - Y12 - Y21) / D
    Z21 = 2 / D
    Z22 = (-1 + Y11 + Y22 - Y12 * Y21) / D
    return np.array([[Z11, Z12], [Z21, Z22]])

Y = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
Z = y2z(Y)

print("Y Parameters:")
print(Y)

print("Z Parameters:")
print(Z)
```

Run these snippets in their respective environments to compare. Both should yield the same Z-parameters.

Comment: Follow up Question: Suppose I have a n*n*z dimension matrix and want to apply this operation. Then how would I be able to do it?